# Adding a value to the state array results in replacement of previous value - React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to add new values from a checkbox to a state array through onchange. But the value replaces the previous value.

```
  const [checked, setCheck] = useState([]);

  const changeCheck = (event,sku) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    setCheck(prevChecked => [...prevChecked,sku]);
  } 


  return(
  <input type="checkbox" checked={checked.includes(props.details.sku)} onChange={(event) => changeCheck(event,props.details.sku)}/>
  )
```

Want to add the props.details.sku value to the checked state array. New values are getting added to the array but old values are getting replaced also means the state array remains of length 1.

Comment: What is props.details.sku? Is it a boolean? And what do you expect your ```checked``` state to be?

Comment: The problem you describe is not reproducible with the code listed - `[...prevChecked, sku]` should work as expected (it will add, not replace), but there is only one `<input>` and the props suggest that there is some parent-child relationship you are not showing us...

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the checkbox state you need to use the previous state and decide whether the checkbox value needs to be added or removed

Also use state updater callback to update the state

```
const [checked, setCheck] = useState([]);

  const changeCheck = (event,sku) =>{
    event.preventDefault();

    setCheck(prevChecked => {
        if(prevChecked.includes(sku)) {
           // checkbox was checked previously so uncheck it
           return prevChecked.filter(i => i !== sku);
        } else {
           // check the checkbox i.e add the id in array
           return [...prevChecked, sku]
        }
    });
  } 


  return(
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checked.includes(props.details.sku)} onChange={(event) => changeCheck(event,props.details.sku)}/>
  )
```

Comment: this would look nice if the question was "how to uncheck...", but not sure if it makes sense to have an array for a single input when addressing the problem that "the state array remains of length 1"